# strong parameters empty and not sure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have been having problems with strong_parameters.  I'll just put the error on here and see if anyone can point me in the right direction...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "true":String):

app/controllers/upvotes_controller.rb:48:in `upvote_params'
app/controllers/upvotes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

Any ideas?

my controller:

```
def upvote_params
params.require(:upvote).permit( :current_user_id, :user_id, :micropost_id, :upvote)
end
```

:upvote is a boolean true or false which I suppose is really 1/0.

console parameters (I hope that is what is needed)

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bdepfs1DBsJOZmYzY1quYU5nGh/f4mktvqS1HWxoepgC/aesaRnhsh+JWgDNmYLif9fh/HGXy9FwZTfpvRTQhg==", "upvote"=>"true", "micropost_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "current_user_id"=>"2", "commit"=>"Save "}
```

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to add both your parameters as submitted (from your console) and the bit of your controller where you do `params.require(...).permit(...)` to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method ´#require´ is actually there for a parameter that is a [hash structure and not a scalar type](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#permitted-scalar-values), like boolean.

The right syntax for your params is most likely:

```
params.permit(:current_user_id, :user_id, :micropost_id, :upvote)
```

Since it seems that your params are not nested in a hash.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that should do it, but I get "Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token, :commit" as another error.

Comment: that is not too bad, as long as you do not do anything with those params.
If you want to avoid that, you can again wrap your params in a hash when sending and use `require` again,

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of `params.require(...).permit(...)`.

When you do:

```
params.require(:upvote).permit( :current_user_id, :user_id, :micropost_id, :upvote)
```

Rails is expecting that you'll have params that look something like:

```
Parameters: {..., "upvote"=>{"micropost_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "current_user_id"=>"2", "upvote"=>"true"}, ...}
```

But, that's not what you have, you have:

```
Parameters: {..., "upvote"=>"true", ...}
```

In which case, Rails is trying to call `permit` on the value of `params[:upvote]` which is a string that contains the value `'true'`.

And that's exactly what the error is telling you.

Perhaps you should take a little longer look at [section 4.5 Strong Parameters](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)  of the [Action Controller Overview](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) docs.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look.

Comment: Actually, I figured out the PROBLEM, which was attr_accessor in my model.  ThAnk You.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to having an attr_accessor in my model file.  SOrry guys, but thanks for your help.